# Firebase login not working firebaseAuthentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting a "Error: An unexpected error has occurred." message when I try Firebase login.

Yesterday I solved the issue by using CMD prompt as administrator instead of the vs code terminal, but today that is not working either.

I've tried:

```
firebase login
firebase login --interactive
firebase login --no-localhost
```

I even tried this based on a suggestion in another stackoverflow:

```
set "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0"
```

I also checked my computer proxy settings and I am not behind a proxy.

What else could it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I don't know why but I closed my cmd prompt and opened it again with administrator prividges then firebase login --no-localhost worked